# Is it possible to perform a full, real transition to another route and transition back in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am running into trouble when transitioning away from a route and then back to it not resulting in full transitions in Ember.

To be more concrete, I have a route `game.new` that handles setting up a new game and then this transitions to `game.play`. The user doens't need to do anything, and so the transition happens automatically in the `afterModel` hook. However, once a game is over, I would like to start a new game by transitioning back to `game.new` and then automatically transitioning back to `game.play`. However, if I have the following hook in `app/routes/game/new.js`:

```
afterModel() {
  this.transitionTo('game.play', game);
}
```

This has the effect of not fully completing the transition and thus the `game/play` route is not fully torn down and set up again.

Is there a way to fully transition from `game.play` to `game.new` and then automatically transition back to `game.play` so that all the content in `game.play` is torn down and recreated?

Comment: if you pass any object to transtionTo method then model hook will not be called. as that will assume the given object is the model for the route. if you do `this.transitionTo('game.play')` it will call all model hooks

Comment: @kumkanillam, I don't mind my model hook not getting called. The problem is the stuff in the outlet is not torn down and redrawn. The new game model causes all the bindings to update, but I would prefer to reinsert all the stuff in the outlet so component `init` and `didInsertElement` hooks get called again.

Answer (score 0):

From Rock and Roll with Ebberjs :

> Controllers in Ember are singletons and thus are not torn down when
>   their route is navigated away from or when their model changes. That
>   means their properties persist while the app lives and anything that
>   needs to be reset needs to be done manually. (...)  Each route has a
>   `resetController` hook that will be called when the route is being
>   exited or when the model for the route changes

I tried to mimic your game with this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/37627da90bb5926abb11185e06913fdb?openFiles=routes.game.play.js%2C&route=%2Fgame%2Fplay) :

```
resetController: function(controller,isExiting ) { 
    if(isExiting) {
    this.score=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I realize I can reset the controller. But I also want to tear down the stuff in the template (outlet) and have it re-inserted. I have a major component that should get redrawn. I realize I could wrap the whole thing in an `{{#unless resetting}}` block and first set `resetting` to true and then to false again and it would have this effect. That just seemed hacky.